# Encoding JSON String with RowCoder

Tags: java, encoding, apache-beam

Let's say I have a JSON String

```json
{"targetTable": "table", "primaryKey": {"A": "a"}, "payload": {"A": "a", "B": "b"}}
```

I am interested in serializing it to a `org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row`, using `RowCoder.of(schema)`, the schema being defined as below

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.RowCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema;

Schema schema1 = Schema.builder()
    .addStringField("A")
    .build();

Schema schema2 = Schema.builder()
    .addStringField("A")
    .addStringField("B")
    .build();

Schema schema = Schema.of(
    Schema.Field.of("targetTable", Schema.FieldType.STRING),
    Schema.Field.of("primaryKey", Schema.FieldType.row(schema1)),
    Schema.Field.of("payload", Schema.FieldType.row(schema2)));

String jsonString = "{\"targetTable\": \"table\", \"primaryKey\": {\"A\": \"a\"}, \"payload\": {\"A\": \"a\", \"B\": \"b\"}}"

InputStream input = ???;
Row row = RowCoder.of(schema).decode(input);

// assert(row.getString("targetTable") == "hello");
// assert(row.getRow("primaryKey").getSchema().equivalent(schemaA1));
// assert(row.getRow("payload").getSchema().equivalent(schemaA0));
```

How can I properly build an `InputStream` to turn my nested JSON structure to a Beam Row? I also tried this but I am confused and not sure about how to correctly build the `byte[]`.

```java
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `JsonToRow` for this which does the string deserialization and `Schema` encoding for you. After defining a `Schema` that ressembles your JSON structure.

Beware that some data types such as `Schema.TypeName.DATETIME` are not supported, you might need to use `Schema.TypeName.STRING` instead.

```java
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.JsonToRow;

PCollection<String> json = ...

PCollection<MyUserType>  = json
  .apply("Parse JSON to Beam Rows", JsonToRow.withSchema(schema))
```

See https://cloud.google.com/architecture/e-commerce/patterns/converting-json